# Hard to read integers in java? Is there any reason behind it?

Tags: java, int

I have to read integers more frequently in Java. So how i should do? What function i have to use?

C/C++ too have buffering concepts but they has a single statement. But in Java we have to call at least 2 function to read an integer.

For an example,

To read an integer from console,

I will use

- `scanf` in C
- `cin` in C++

But in Java,

```
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(System.in)); String number = bufferedreader.readLine();

int value = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

or

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
int i = scan.nextInt();
```

Someone please explain me: Can I have a simpler version than these similar to `cin` or `scanf` (A one line statement).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is madness.  This. is. JAVA!

Comment: Doesn't get much easier than the `Scanner` example you've got there!

Comment: I don't see anything too bad about `scan.nextInt()`.  You could call the variable `s` if it's the character count that concerns you. :)

Comment: wasn't this question just deleted once?

Comment: @Mathias Schwarz yes sir. but the question is closed while i was editing the question (to make it clear). and i was still eager to know the answers thats why.

Comment: If you have a programming requirement of doing it with only 1 command, maybe stick with C or BASIC or Python or many more.

Comment: @Muthu, Java's support for console input isn't that great, most of the support is for GUI applications.

Comment: funny :). He asked the same question in [another place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523018/how-can-i-read-integers-from-console), and there he got 5 votes down. Re-asked and gained 3 answers, 1 vote-up... some patience and help would have made the first question be answered without problems.

Comment: Java's design philosophy seems to be "the most boilerplate code, the better".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe `Scanner` provides the simplest interface. I don't believe there is a simpler approach provided by the standard API. (You could of course encapsulate the snippet in a method, and call the method instead.)

The only one-liner I can come up with is the obvious

```
int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Comment: can i have a function like cin. a single word statement

Comment: @Muthu, You could wrap it in a method, which leads to more code, but enables getting an `int` in a "single word statement"...

Comment: @Muthu No, you need a method (like nextInt) and an object (like Scanner) The scanner is really the simplest you can get.

Comment: thank you sir. I am clear now

Answer (score 3):

There is not a one line version, what you have is basically what there is. Java is an object oriented language, so you create the object (The scanner, or BufferedReader) then use that object to read a line.

I would use Scanner. Think of it like importing stdin in C++. You create the Scanner once, then use a single line (scanner.nextInt()) to get the int. If you think about it like that, the command is basically a single line.

Comment: thank you sir. I am clear now.

Comment: Not a problem, the little changes between languages are often the hardest to understand

Comment: Although C++ is not strictly object oriented like Java, cin is an object.  I think the root of confusion is that because of the way #include works (as opposed to Java's import) the object is created and linked to stdin behind the scenes and novice developers who aren't savvy on the behind the scenes workings don't realize this.

Comment: Much appreciated Matt. I have actually never developed in C++ more than hello world/converting celsius to fahrenheit, etc. and just assumed cin was the equivalent of an operator rather than an object.

Comment: @Matt yes sir I understood,and I now eager to know whether it is possible to create a class in java which does all the functions of creating and linking to stdin. so that in future the developers of java can simply import this class.

Answer (score -1):

Scanner is the easiest to use, there isn't a simple scanf because java is an object oriented programming language.  A scanner object makes it very simple to read items, I'm not sure what your problem here is.

Comment: thank you sir. I am clear now