# Java: How to get values from console input easily

Tags: java, string, console, split, readline

As a user I type following command into the java console:

```
!login <Username> <udpPort>
```

so, i.e.

```
!login Bob 2233
```

What I need is to easily get the values from this input:

```
String username = "Bob";
int port = 2233;
```

I am using a BufferedReader to get the input.

I already tried: But of course this is not working. But thats what I would like to have:

```
String [] input = in.readReadLine(); //ofcourse this is not working
```

Then I can easily assign the values:

```
String username = input[2]; //save "Bob"
int port = Integer.parseInt(input[3]); //save 2233
```

Any advices appreciated,
Dave

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523418/hard-to-read-integers-in-java-is-there-any-reason-behind-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BufferedReaeder` [readLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method return `String`.

Once you get String, you need to either `Split();` (or) `StringTokenizer` to get as separate Strings.

Comment: Yes. I just used this: String[] sI = in.readLine().split(" ");

Answer (score 2):

Scanner class is best suited for taking input from console.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ConsoleInput { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The input is : "+ input);  
    }  
}
```

This is a simple class demonstrating the use of Scanner class in Java. It has several method that can help you in reading different types of inputs for ex- `int`, `char`, `String`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `java.util.Scanner` as below:

```
  Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  inputScanner.next(); //reads whole word
  inputScanner.nextInt(); //reads whole numeral
  inputScanner.nextLine(); //reads whole line
```

Now using  `nextLine`, read the line and split

```
   String line = inputScanner.nextLine();
   String[] commands = line.split(" "); //splits space delimited words in the line
```

or using `next()`, read one command at time e.g.

```
  command[0] = inputScanner.next(); 
  command[1] = inputScanner.next();
```

**Or you can use `next()` and `nextInt()`**

```
  String username = inputScanner.next();  //save "Bob"
  int port = inputScanner.nextInt(); //save 2233
```

More method details here. [**Scanner**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
String [] input = in.readReadLine().split("\\s+"); // split the line at spaces
```

And use index 1 and 2 because array index starts from 0 not 1

```
String username = input[1]; //get the second element of the array
int port = Integer.parseInt(input[2]); //get the third element and parse
```